Scroll to Specific ID
Take a look at the following code:


$(document).ready(function(){

  var isScrolling = false;

  $("#main_box .main-btn").click(function(){
    if (isScrolling) return;

    isScrolling = true;

    var targetId = $(this).attr("id");
    var targetPosition = $("#" + targetId).offset().top;
    var scrollDistance = targetPosition - $(window).scrollTop();
    var maxScrollTop = $("#main_box").offset().top + $("#main_box").height();

    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Math.min(scrollDistance, maxScrollTop)
    }, 1000, function(){
      isScrolling = false;
    });
  });
});
    .up-page {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #main_box {
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 2rem auto 3rem;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    }

    .content-up {
        display: block;
        width: 99%;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #f00;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .main-btn {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 15px auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f00, inset 0 0 200px #0028ff;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .main-btn p {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 5px 0 10px;
    }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="up-page"></div>

    <div id="main_box">

        <h1>main box</h1>

        <div class="content-up">
            <h2>content-up</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="btn_tag_1" class="main-btn">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="btn_tag_2" class="main-btn">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="btn_tag_3" class="main-btn">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="btn_tag_4" class="main-btn">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="btn_tag_5" class="main-btn">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>

    </div>



When I click on elements with the class .main-btn, the page scrolls up correctly.
However, the problem is that the scroll passes the #main_box ID and stops slightly above it. This is wrong, and the scroll should never pass the #main_box ID under any circumstances.
In the above example, this problem is not that serious, but when I use this code in my main project, the scroll completely passes the ID I want and goes beyond the desired section!
Now I just want you to change the jQuery code for me so that the scroll never passes the #main_box ID (not even 1px).
I have tried many ways and have not been able to find a solution to my problem by searching the internet. Maybe I don't even know what to search for to solve my problem.
In any case, I have been able to write the jQuery code above, which needs a little editing to achieve my main goal.
Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Just edit these lines (I hope you don't need it in middle):
$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $("#main_box").offset().top-20
}, 1000, function(){
  isScrolling = false;
});


thank you so much. You solved a big problem for me.
